# WebSphere + IHS/ODR plugin-cfg.xml with /ibm/saml20/*

Tags: apache, cluster-computing, httpd.conf, websphere-liberty

we are using:

- WLP 18.0.0.3
- IBM HTTP Server 8.5.5.12

we are facing a following problem in our environemnt:

Two different applications with feature samlWeb-2.0 enabled on same server are in conflict when redirected back from ADFS, maybe due to routing caused by generated plugin-cfg.xml below.

In generated plugin-cfg.xml we have :

```
<UriGroup Name="applicationA_URIs">
    ...
    <Uri Name="/ibm/saml20/*" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID"/>
    ...
</UriGroup>
<UriGroup Name="applicationB_URIs">
    ...
    <Uri Name="**/ibm/saml20/***" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID"/>
    ...
</UriGroup>
```

In this case adfs authentication fails due to ODR doesnt know where to route back authenticated user.

We changed it to following:

```
<UriGroup Name="applicationA_URIs">
    ...
    <Uri Name="/ibm/saml20/applicationA_SP/*" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID"/>
    ...
</UriGroup>
<UriGroup Name="applicationB_URIs">
    ...
    <Uri Name="/ibm/saml20/applicationB_SP/*" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID"/>
    ...
</UriGroup>
```

So when Uri was changed explicitly to correct SP endpoint it started to work. Problem is that these changes had been done manually -> Is there any way how to specify explicit SP context root for saml for particular application in collective ?

Comment: If you're using the ODR / Intelligent Management, these generated stanzas are not really used at runtime.  You should instead check the output of /server-status to see what the dynamic view of the apps are.

But f you made a change and it worked, does it mean you are not using the ODR / Intelligent Management features in the plugin?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, if they're really on the same server, the WAS Plugin can't misroute it.    I could only imagine a problem if they were on different servers and the plugin-cfg.xml files were merged. Can yoou elaborate?

Comment: there also seem to be masked characters (*) added to the XML so it's really difficult to tell what your generated config looks like, much less what the requests look like on the wire.